# PayPal Sandbox - Subscription Button - Test Account - Link Invalid

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I'm trying to test a **really simple subscribe button** using the PayPal API.

First and foremost, the error I'm getting:

`The link you have used to enter the PayPal system is invalid. Please review the link and try again.`

**I'm using PayPal's own code** from sandbox for the generated button. The *only* change I made was the IPN callback for debugging purposes.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="SUGR2DWLNM38U">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit">
    <img src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

*Note: The sandbox form **action** is correct according to the docs (whole thing was auto generated)*

Yes, **I'm logging in with the test account I have created**:

[image]

After reading through the horrible docs and webpages that seem to go to the wrong place, I'm hitting a stump and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have:

- Setup a new paypal BUSINESS account.
- Setup a new sandbox BUSINESS account.
- On the sandbox account, I have created a test PERSONAL account
- On the sandbox account, I have created a test subscription button
- The test subscription button has an added callback for the IPN to a php file I'm `tail -f`'ing on

According to the docs, this is all I need, but clicking the button gives me the error above.

What am I missing??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try creating a non hosted clear text button so that I can see what your button is passing over to determine what's causing the error.  When creating the button, on step 2 of the button creation process uncheck the option to save button at PayPal.  Then once your code is generated, on that same page click the link to remove code protection.  This should give you the HTML code for your button.  This is what I would need to see, so that I can test your button and determine whats causing the issue.

One thing to check is to make sure that the seller account that you are using is verified, and the email address that you are using as well with the test account is linked and verified on the test sandbox seller account.

Comment: Sure, the new, non-hosted markup with non protected code is here: http://pastebin.com/QfHDzS1g

Comment: Your button should be working now.  The email address on the account was not verified.  I manually verified it on my side, and tested the button and it is working now.

Comment: The email address on the actual test sandbox seller account was not verified.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help on that!! Could you update your answer with this simple thing - I'm sure it'll help someone else :)